# Modify NodeJS core programs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I tried to add some custom functions into the FS module of NodeJS, this module is part of NodeJS' core programs. I found the corresponding file (fs.js) in the following location: /usr/lib/nodejs. The problem was that the changes that I've made seemed to not affect anything when the corresponding module and function was called.

What I did was I added a function like this in /usr/lib/nodejs/fs.js:

```
      fs.someRandomFunc = function(){return 'Yeah!'}
```

However, when I called the function, it replied :

```
      var fs = require('fs')
      console.log(fs.someRandomFunc())

      // Error Message
      TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'someRandomFunc'
```

By the way, this also happens to the other core modules, such as module.js and path.js. Does this happen because NodeJS caches the core JS program instead of loading it from /usr/lib/nodejs?

Any idea to resolve this issue would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

`fs` is part of NodeJS' [Core Modules](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_core_modules). As such, it is compiled into binary and distributed. So modifying the source is not going to take effect unless you recompile them.

It is anyway not a good idea to modify Node's source files directly. What you can/should instead is extend the existing `fs` module with your own functions, like [graceful-fs](https://github.com/isaacs/node-graceful-fs/blob/master/graceful-fs.js) does, or replace it entirely with your version, like [fs-extra](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra) does.